# IIS Application pool stops automatically

Tags: wcf, iis, windows-7, c#-3.0

I hosted some service in my local IIS with Application Pool Identity as Identity in application pool. 
Now I tried to add another WCF Application and set its identity as application pool identity, but the application pool will stop when it receives the first request. 
When I tried with an existing application pool, its working.After googling I tried, to find some logs in event viewer, but there were no error.
**If I set my user id and password, then its works fine.** 
How can I troubleshoot and figure out whats the issue with **Application Pool Identity**?